# XChaCha20-Poly1305 vs Plain ChaCha20-Poly1305 performance

Tags: encryption, authenticated-encryption, chacha, performance

I know that the security of both are the same (only nonce size is different). But which one is faster and better to use, when encrypting a lot of files (500+, from 1MB to 200MB)?

Comment: Do you want us to try these performances? Of course, xChaCha20-Poly1305 is better since it [enables longer nonces so that random nonces are secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87347/18298)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ChaCha20-Poly1305 is slightly more performant because there's no [HChaCha20 subkey derivation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-xchacha#section-2.3). If you benchmark the two, this will be detectable. However, in the real world, the difference is negligible.

If you don't need random nonces, use ChaCha20-Poly1305 (the IETF version). Otherwise, or when unsure, use XChaCha20-Poly1305 with a random nonce each time. Just don't let the nonce repeat for a given key with either.

File encryption is often done with a unique key per file and a counter nonce that gets incremented for each chunk (e.g. the [STREAM construction](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/189)). This prevents chunk reordering easily. I discussed this in more detail [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/102600/102678).